# Loop doesn't hold the value

Tags: procedural-programming

My program doesn't hold the value in a variable as I want it. I want to attach the calculated value as a list in a variable. What is wrong here?

```
t = 10
While[t >= 1,
   sw = 30^2*(StandardDeviation[x]/Sqrt[11 - t])^2 + 10^2*(StandardDeviation[y]/Sqrt[t])^2; 
  t = t - 1];
```

Comment: Why would `sw = Table[30^2*(StandardDeviation[x]/Sqrt[11 - t])^2 + 10^2*(StandardDeviation[y]/Sqrt[t])^2, {t, 10, 1, -1}]` not work?

Comment: hmm It works properly but, how would i do it as as loop?

Comment: Easy: [don't.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/34893).

Answer (score 3):

[J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-is-somewhat-okay) and [AccidentalFourierTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34893/accidentalfouriertransform) have already shown you the standard answer in the comment, but if you still insist on making your loop work, you can use the following:

```
Clear@sw
sw = {}; (sw = a_) ^:= (sw := #) &[sw~Join~{a}]

t = 10
While[t >= 1, 
 sw = 30^2 (StandardDeviation[x]/Sqrt[11 - t])^2 + 10^2 (StandardDeviation[y]/Sqrt[t])^2;
  t = t - 1]

sw == Table[
  30^2 (StandardDeviation[x]/Sqrt[11 - t])^2 + 10^2 (StandardDeviation[y]/Sqrt[t])^2, {t,
    10, 1, -1}]
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this then..

```
t = 10;
s = {};
While[t >= 1, 
sw = 30^2*(StandardDeviation[x]/Sqrt[11 - t])^2 + 
10^2*(StandardDeviation[y]/Sqrt[t])^2; AppendTo[s, sw];
t--];
s
```